# front end to linux std mailbox for development purposes

Tags: linux, mailbox

I am actually a software developer, do have a fair amount of linux experience as a user though since 1997. I am normally on stackoverflow.com, please excuse me if this question isn't appropriate here.

I am working on a web project. We send out emails. I work locally on a linux box. When coding I use my local mailboxes to check what's been sent. Emails sent out to valid email addresses are not arriving at my official mailbox; they might be stopped by the provider's mail servers (gmail, yahoo).

Now, we are sending out HTML mails too. I need to check how they look like.

Is there a GUI frontend to the standard linux BSD mailbox?
Or should I install some IMAP/POP server for this?
Will such server get the emails sent to username@localhost ?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/123900/is-there-a-way-to-read-command-line-local-mail-in-os-xs-mail-application-or-ano/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird should be able to read from the mail spool using the movemail account type: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Help_Documentation:Creating_an_Account